# Cannot create property 'callback' on number - jsPDF in Angular 9

Tags: angular, jspdf

Code:

import jsPDF  from 'jspdf';

@ViewChild('htmlData') htmlData: ElementRef;

public downloadPDF(): void {
let DATA = this.htmlData.nativeElement;

```
let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

let handleElement = {
  '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};
doc.html(DATA.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
  'width': 200,
  'elementHandlers': handleElement
});

doc.save(this.certificateData.tagNo+'.pdf');
```

}

Comment: Could you please share the **this.certificateData** contains?

Comment: import { TimeSeriesSample } from "./timeSeriesSample";

export class CertificateData
{
  id: number;
  isApproved: boolean;
  testDate: Date;
  tagNo: string;
  platform: string;
  coldDiffTestPressure: number;
  serialNo: string;
  setPressure: number;
  valveType: string;

  isolationValveTested: string;
  isolationValveLeakage: number;
  isolationValveTestTimeSeriesData: TimeSeriesSample[];

Answer (score 9):

The signature for `doc.html()` is different than `doc.fromHTML()`.

You need to do it this way instead:

```js
doc.html(DATA.innerHTML, {
  'x': 15,
  'y': 15,
  'width': 200,
  'elementHandlers': handleElement
});
```